# "stop-on-error" column does not show up

Tags: testcomplete

I am new to testcomplete.Just trying our some sample exercises and trying to understand this automation tool. So I was trying to automate navigating to a particular page on a website. I am doing the record and playback feature. However, when I line up multiple tests and try to run them together, the 'stop-on-error' column does not show up. The only columns I see are "Name, Test, Count, Timeout,min, Parameters and Description"  I do not see the "stop-on-error" column. Any idea what could be the issue? Do I need to turn on something?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project Playlist, right-click the whitespace to get a pop dialogue, then select "Field Chooser".  You can add the "Stop on Error" column from there.